# How to get mutation is done?(ReplicatedMergeeTree)

Tags: clickhouse

In my limited experience with CH Cluster, now I have two nodes, using replicatedMergeTree,1 sharding 2 replicas. I meet the problem that do data synchronize from Mysql.

When to update the table, I first delete data some days ago and count the table record where date >days_ago, and then load data from Mysql,codes like follows:

```
delete from ods.my_table  where data_date>:days_ago;
# here to check if record count is zero
select count(*) from ods.my_table where data_date>:days_ago;
# if count(*) =0 ,load data ; else wait
insert into ods.my_table select * from mysql('xxx'......) where data_date>:days_ago;
```

but I get zero records in CH ods.my_table where data_date>:days_ago;
if I run it again, it will have data; and run it again, it will be zero..., the result is like that: when it's zero, rerun will be ok; when it's not zero, rerun will not be ok.

I analyzed the log, and found that when the mutation is not done the insert statement has been executed. So, data missed.

I try to check if the mutation is finished on the table, but I could not find any solution, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

just add table TTL definition on clickhouse side and forget about manual delete

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/#mergetree-table-ttl

you can add TTL to exists clickhouse MergeTree table

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/ttl/